# applying arithmetic function on different tables in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

i have two tables

```
table1 sanction
table2 collection
```

i want to `select amount from sanction - amount recovered` from collection 
and output the difference.

```
select SUM(sanction.san_recover-collection.amount) as total where client_id=?
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to first join both the tables and then can apply the difference -

```
SELECT SUM(S.san_recover-C.amount) as total
FROM sanction S
JOIN collection C ON S.client_id = C.client_id
WHERE S.client_id=?         -- Specific client ID
```

Comment: client_id in where clause is ambigous

Comment: This won't find those with sanctions but no collections (a left join would be required for that) and if either values is null the sum will be null, and it won't findd those where collection but no sanctions (a full join ?)

Comment: @gulshankumar, I have edited the answer. Please try now. Also if you have some other requirements as per the comment from P.Salmon, Please edit your question.

Comment: @P.Salmon, Nice observations. I think we should left this decision on OP only.

Comment: RESOLVED  String sql= "select ((select sum(san_recover) from sanction  where client_id=?)- (select sum(amount) from collection where client_id=?)) " ;